# Least Absolute Values Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, mean-absolute-deviation, least-absolute-deviations

I have the data:

```
x <- c(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)

y <- c(2.06, 2.12, 2.32, 2.02, 2.76, 3.04, 2.83, 3.15, 3.36, 3.68, 3.96)
```

I must to use the $RSS$ below to find a regression line for the data.

How could I use $\text{RSS}=\sum_{i=1}^n \vert y_i-a-bx_i\vert$ to find the corresponding line for the data set above?

Comment: Sum of squares or absolute values? You said squares but wrote the math of absolute values.

Comment: absolute values, excuse me.

Comment: You also say that you must use $RSS$, so do you need to use the residual sum of squares or the residual sum of absolute values?

Comment: I need to use $\text{RSS}=\sum_{i=1}^n \vert y_i-a-bx_i\vert$. That is the residual sum of absolute values, allright?

Comment: Look at this, i'm stuck in exercise 2. 
https://academic.uprm.edu/wrolke/esma6616/hw10.html

Comment: So fit the line that way. Where are you encountering a problem?

Comment: In standard linear regression, you try to minimize the $RSS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-a-bx_{i})^{2}$, where the minimization in most cases is straightforward I believe. Now in your case, you have to minimize something that includes an absolute value, which is not so trivilia. In this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations they propose some solutions.

Comment: I tried to build a method, based on slopes between the data points. But the line always crosses two data points. And teacher said me that's wrong.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Yeah, that's correct. I suposse that need to use a optimization package in RStudio, but i don't know which one.

Comment: With a quick search, I found the following http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/L1pack/html/lad.html , I'm sure that you will find more literature on that topic.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look for.